# Do functions in ordered by values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making text-based RPG and I thought that it would be more than good to have more than 2 fighters at a time.

So I have function `attack()` in my battle function. I would like to make that my program calls this function with name of attacker, like `attack("player")`. This with everyone whom are in battle, in order, depending on their speed (which is an integer variable).

I know it can be made like this:

```
if playerspeed<enemyspeed:
    attack(enemyname)
    attack("player")
if playerspeed>enemyspeed:
    attack("player")
    attack(enemyname)
```

But if there are e.g. four fighters, this would be painful to do. So is there any sensible way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your names in a list, and order them by attack speed:

```
fighters = [(playerspeed, 'player'), (enemyspeed, enemyname)]
fighters.sort()
for speed, fighter in fighters:
    attack(fighter)
```

If you used classes for your players and enemies instead, you could store their speed in an attribute on the object and sort by that attribute instead of having to create tuples with the information:

```
fighters = [player, enemy]
fighters.sort(key=lambda f: f.speed)
for fighter in fighters:
    fighter.attack(fighters)
```

where the objects also have `attack()` methods; here I assumed that perhaps that method would like to know who is all involved in a fight.